# Display the mathematical difference between the title of 2 checkbox elements

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form that uses checkboxes similar to the one below

```
<Form>
 <table>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" width="15"><input name="switch" title="0" id="radio17" value="Free Shipping" checked="checked" type="radio" />
      </td>
      <td>Free Shipping</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" width="15"><input name="switch" title="38" id="radio18" value="Standard Shipping" type="radio" />
      </td>
      <td>Standard Shipping
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and what i need is the difference in price, which is denoted by the title, to be displayed next to the name.So if Free Shipping is selected the output should look like "Free Shipping [+0]" and Standard shipping will look like "Standard Shipping [+38]"

I am just learning javascript, so that would be prefered, but anything will do if it works.

Comment: $("input:checked"){  {
val = parseInt($(this).attr("title"));
document.writeIn(val - parseInt(document.getElementById("radio17").title));
}

Comment: "to be displayed next to the name", what name?

Comment: what html prints out, ie Free Shipping or Standard shipping

Comment: Based on your comment, you're using jquery, that tag should be included.  Also, include IN the question the code that you have tried which is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pHMvP/)?

```
<form> 
  <label><input type="radio" name="switch" title="Free Shipping" id="freeshipping" value="0" checked="checked" type="radio" />Free Shipping</label>    
  <label><input type="radio" name="switch" title="Standard Shipping" id="standardshipping" value="38" />Standard Shipping</label>
  <div>Selected shipping method: <span id="shippingtitle"> </span> [+<span id="shippingcost"> </span>]</div> 
</form>
```

```
window.onload = function(){
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName('switch').length; ++i){
        document.getElementsByName('switch')[i].onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById('shippingtitle').firstChild.data = this.title;
            document.getElementById('shippingcost').firstChild.data = this.value;
        }
    }
};
```

```
label{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    width:30%;
}
form{
    max-width:500px;
}
```

It seems that you're just learning JavaScript. That's great, but don't use a helicopter if you're trying to steer a car (learn basic JavaScript and read a little bit about the DOM before you use jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

I would access the radio elements by id and then update their parent element's sibling element's text to include the value of the "title" attribute of the radio button.  For example:

```javascript
function showPriceDifference(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id)
    , price = el.getAttribute('title');
  el.parentElement.nextElementSibling.innerHTML += ' [+' + price + ']';
}
showPriceDifference('radio17');
showPriceDifference('radio18');
```